# CSS Target span after specific icon class

Tags: css

My theme uses the following syntax. I will need to target the `span` after the icon class `fa-lock`

```
<i class="shiftnav-icon fa fa-lock"></i><span>My item</span>
```

I tried:

```
.shiftnav .fa-lock span:first-of-type {color: #c1c1c1;}
```

But that doesnt work for some reason. Any ideas please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.shiftnav-icon.fa-lock + span` selector.

`+` is a [`Adjacent sibling combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and it will select `span` element that is right after `.shiftnav-icon.fa-lock` element

```css
.shiftnav-icon.fa-lock + span {color: red;}
```

```html
<i class="shiftnav-icon fa fa-lock"></i><span>My item</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

.shiftnav-icon.fa-lock + span:first-of-type {color: #c1c1c1;}

Your 'shiftnav-icon' and 'fa-lock' are in the same tag - so there should be no gap between them when you use them.
The 'span' is the next element - so use the '+' symbol to target it.

Check out Adjacent sibling combinator here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors